# Error 500 when using Fiddler to POST to ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to learn how to create my own Web API with Visual Studio 2012. I currently have two database tables set up through the Models I have below.

The Countries table is nice and simple. I can successfully POST a new entry with Fiddler. However, when it comes to trying to POST to the Players table, I'm getting a 500 Error. Of course, I have no idea where I'm going wrong.

**Player.cs**

```
public class Player
{
    public Guid PlayerId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Town { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string State { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateJoined { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties
    public Country Country { get; set; }
}
```

**Countries.cs**

```
    public class Country
{
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following Content Type set in the Fiddler Request Header:

> Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

The data I'm trying to POST to the Player table is this:

> {"PlayerId":"hfjdfk","Username":"TickledPink","Address":"My Address","Address2":"","Town":"Llanerchymedd","State":"Anglesey", "Postcode":"LL71","Email":"myemail@me.net","Telephone":"1234567","Mobile":"456789","DateJoined":"","CountryId":"1"}

Answer (score 1):

I know little to nothing about Web API, but is "hfjdfk" a valid GUID?

Comment: Hmmm ... good question. I assumed it would take any string as a GUID. I'll take a look.

Comment: I've just tried it. It probably wasn't a valid GUID. I've replaced it with what should be a valid string but still the same issue.

Comment: Can you step into the web api code? This is how I often resolve, or track down the issue. A 500 doesn't give you much to work with.

Comment: I've tried it. The breakpoints in my PlayerController class aren't being triggered which suggests it isn't even executing the code. That being the case I might suspect an issue with Fiddler and the fact I'm running it on Windows 8 but I can POST to the Countries table just fine ... if I knew the order of execution for the classes in the Web API scaffolding then I might be able to pin down the problem and work from there.

Comment: Can you POST to the Player table successfully without Fiddler?

Comment: Well, I shoved breakpoints at the start of every function within the PlayerController class, even the ones I thought it wouldn't touch. Just as well I did as it's jumped straight into the controller's Dispose function. Looking at the stack trace it's throwing an exception after POST. There was a problem with the CountryId property. Apparently it needed a [DataMember(IsRequired=true)] attribute added to it if it's given a [Required] attribute. The easiest thing for me for now was to just remove the [Required] attribute. It now posts okay :)